# using cocoa-touch to build apps; do other languages support it?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Correct me if I'm wrong, because I very well could be. My understanding is that cocoa-touch is the framework that objective-c uses to interact with the special parts of the phone, right? For example, cocoa touch has things like NSTimer and NSString, it supports the logic to access the GPS chip through location services delegates and accelerometer data and all that other stuff right?

So, apple could support another language in the future like, say, java (I know its a reach) but java could never truly be used to write an app because it doesn't have cocoa-touch, which is what is needed to access the special parts of the phone. In fact, I don't think you could use any language at all without cocoa touch because it wouldn't have access to or be able to build an interface.

In theory you could use XML files to do it, but there is still so much missing because you don't have cocoa-touch. And if so, are there any other languages that might support cocoa-touch currently or sometime in the future? If this is the case, I'd say that apple supporting these languages doesn't make a damn bit of difference if they don't have cocoa-touch. Does that sound right?

Comment: There are a number of Cocoa or CocoaTouch bindings to other languages: MonoTouch, PyObjC, RubyCocoa, and there is in fact (or was) a Java-Cocoa bridge on OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this exists. Mono-Touch by Xamarin uses C# to program for the iPhone and they built C# wrapper classes that call the Objective C methods. This is fully supported in the App Store and I myself have written several apps using C# and Mono Touch. Not only can I use their supplied wrappers around existing Cocoa Touch libraries, but I can also create my own wrapper C# libraries around mine or other peoples Objective C libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Tip: When you have a general question, try reading Wikipedia first. Such as: [Cocoa (API)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_%28API%29)

> So, apple could support another language in the future like, say, java

Apple did indeed support Java use in Xcode and in Cocoa development. They offered a Cocoa-Java bridge, now cancelled.

Other bindings are available. See that Wikipedia article.

> In theory you could use XML files to do it

Apple does indeed use XML as part of the development process. XML is the 'x' in xib. A [xib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder) is the XML format of their binary format, [nib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_Builder).

Comment: I always figured "MacOS X" was the 'x' in 'xib' since "NeXT" is the 'n' in 'nib'. Perhaps it just made sense to change the extension to 'xib' when they changed the format to **XML**, built Interface Builder into **Xcode**, and wanted to recognize that the name of the OS had changed to **MacOS X**.

Comment: i know they use xml files to describe their interfaces. i was trying to make a point. did anybody get it?

thanks for the answer i appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

> but java could never truly be used to write an app because it doesn't have cocoa-touch

There are reasons that Java can't be used (mainly, the JVM doesn't exist on iOS), but lack of Cocoa Touch isn't really one of them. It's possible for [other languages to interface with Objective-C frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_%28API%29#Implementations_and_Bindings), and in the past Apple even developed a [Java bridge](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000024.php) that made it possible to access Objective-C frameworks from Java under MacOS X.

Comment: once again i wasnt trying to say java could write apps, i was using it as an example language that i was pretty sure didnt have cocoa-touch. i know it needs a JVM

Comment: Your assertion was that "apple supporting these languages doesn't make a damn bit of difference if they don't have cocoa-touch", and my point is that a language doesn't necessarily need to be Objective-C to bind to an Objective-C framework. Java is a poor choice of example because Java could link to Obj-C frameworks, but there are other factors that prevent the use of Java on iOS.